# 'Too good': Hyperbole, fossil, calque, quirk, something else?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-origin, subcontinental-english, compliment

I often hear the exclamation "too good" in Indian English. Sometimes it describes food, sometimes music, sometimes an event, anything really; it's rather versatile, common enough to have been included in this [listicle from *LearningIndia.in*](https://learningindia.in/references/indian-english-dictionary/), which explains:

> ***too good***: extremely good, NOT excessively good

For a (Hinglish) usage example, see [this](https://youtu.be/LK2XYD72EC8?t=1719) video where a judge uses it to praise a performance; it pretty clearly illustrates how it's used.

I wish to know the origin and extent of this phrase's use in India. Indians are wont to translate literally; is this an example of that? What was the original phrase/language? I can't think of any native phrase for this to have been paralleled off of. Is it simply hyperbole? Is it a random quirk that somehow gained popularity? When did it come about? Is it a British thing that was preserved in India?

Comment: Where do you hear this? In India, or among Indians living outside the country?

Comment: The use of "too" as "a mere intensifier" is in [Merriam-Webster (2c)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too) and the OED; the OED's first citation is the *Ayenbite of Inwyt* (1340).

Comment: @Xanne - both, but mainly in India.